# jQuery: Get .timeago() to work on elements loaded after DOM ready (Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

Using pageless1 to trigger an ajax load of older, timestamped content onto the end of the page, I need [.timeago()](http://timeago.yarp.com/) to act upon those newly loaded dates. It works on the content loaded the first time you arrive at the page, but not the content loaded via Ajax later.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For running *plugins* (things not event handler based) you can still use the [`.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/livequery/), like this:

```
$('.selector').livequery(function() {
  $(this).timeago();
});
```

If it's an event handler, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) works, or if it's a plugin you can also run the plugins on loaded content, for example:

```
$.ajax({
  //options...
  success: function(data) {
    //do stuff
    $('.selector', data).timeago();
  }
});
```

This runs the plugin on that selector, but *only* for elements that came back in that AJAX response, by using the context argument of [`$(selector,  [context])`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

Comment: Nick: Is there any harm in calling `$('.selector').livequery(function(){$(this).timeago();});` after already binding it originally during doc ready (using `jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();`)? Or is this essentially like refreshing the timestamps using livequery?

Comment: A jQuery plugin (i.e.: timeago) will only be initialized on an element once, so calling it multiple times will not cause any problems. In contrast, binding event handlers multiple times can cause problems (`$(myElement).on('click', ...);`)