# How to inject some JS code after every remote call in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, timeago

So I'm using [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin in my Rails 3 app, wrapping it within this function (note than the timeout just keeps the timeago strings updated to the minute at every moment):

```
function doTimeago() {
  $('.timeago').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('active')!='yes') {
      $this.timeago().data('active','yes');
    }
  });
}
```

And then in my `application.js`

```
$(function() {
  doTimeago();
}
```

This works great until I load some elements using `remote` calls. I researched a bit and found no working solution. I'm not happy adding `livequery` plugin as suggested [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414890/jquery-get-timeago-to-work-on-elements-loaded-after-dom-ready-ajax) since it seems deprecated.

I was thinking of adding this JS code to the end of every `js.erb` file in my app, but it feels really duplicated and nasty.

```
doTimeago();
```

Question part 1: ¿Is there an easy way to inject that code after every `js.erb` execution?

Question part 2: ¿How do I achieve my primary goal of having ajaxy loaded elements work with `timeago`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind it to `ajaxComplete` event, like this:

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function(){
  do_timeago();
});
```

BTW, I didn't understand your timeout in `do_timeago` function. Also, JS best practices are a bit different than ruby ones, consider rename your function to something like `doTimeago`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks !!! Thanks also for the renaming suggestion, I did and updated the question. About the timeout, this is used to have the timeago strings updated to the minute all the time: after 3 minutes have passed from the page load, a `1 minute ago` string will be updated to `4 minutes ago`. I also updated my question to avoid confusion. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. About the timeout, well, I don't need to do that. Timeago.js automatically refresh every minute. Take a look: http://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js , CTRL+F refreshMillis. cheers

Comment: Great to know, thanks again! Tested and working. Then it seems this wiki page is deprecated, isn't it? https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/wiki/Tips